# How to set gradient drawable as backgroundTint attribute on FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, drawable, gradient, background-color, floating-action-button

I would like to use a gradient color instead of the traditional solid color for a Floating Action Button.

I already know how to modify the background color of the button, using `ColorStateList`. Is there a way to implement the following drawable as a background tint color?

**overlay.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient
        android:startColor="#c25f82"
        android:endColor="#5a3e60"
        android:angle="-270" />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can set a Gradient to a FAB, I've just found a heck.

1.) Create a **gradient.xml** in *drawable* folder and add the following code in it,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <gradient
        android:type="linear"
        android:angle="0"
        android:startColor="#03a9f4"
        android:endColor="#e91e63" />
</shape>
```

2.) In your **dimens.xml** add this piece of line,

```
<dimen name="design_fab_image_size" tools:override="true">56dp</dimen>
```

3.) In your Fab add `android:src="@drawable/gradient"`

Answer (score 0):

No. As you already noticed, tint is always a solid color. You can set anything as a background, but I guess such approach would break the support FAB.